# indexing in r dataframe with NAs

Tags: r, indexing

I am a beginner in r and trying to analyse a complicated data set, so bear with me please.
I have a data frame with 3 columns. The first is doy (day of year - just a running number instead of a date), the second is bbb (just a different number for each day), and the third is a reference about when I took a measurement. I have 20 days on which I took measurements and they are different amounts of days apart. So most of the third column is NA, but the measurement days are 1,2,3...

```
doy  bbb   mday
1    4     NA
2    7     1
3    2     NA
4    9     2
```

etc. I have to add up the amounts of bbb between each mday. I have been practising the intricacies of r by ignoring the mday column and using the other 2. Eg:

```
sum(df$bbb[df$doy==1:4])
[1] 22
```

So far, so good. Whenever I try to get the bbb for a particular mday, however, I get an answer of a lot of NAs, with a number in between (sometimes the correct one). When I do this:

```
sum(df$bbb[df$mday],na.rm=T)
```

it gives me a sum of the first 20 (because the amount of mdays is 20) bbbs, irrelevant of whether there is a number in the mday column or not (that is, the first 20 values of bbb). I'm not sure if this is a dataframe formatting problem or if there is something in the code that is wrong (even though it works when I use doy instead of mday). Sometimes it happens that it gives me some random number and I can't for the life of me figure out where it got it from. Eg:

```
sum(df$bbb[df$mday==1:4],na.rm=T)
```

As a result it gives me the bbb of mday 2. I don't know why. Alright, I hope this is a clear enough explanation of what my problem is. I guess my question is: how to I get the sum of bbb for the days between mday 1+2 (excl. mday 1, but incl. mday 2) and all the other mdays (I was assuming that I will have to use a for loop eventually)? And if you could also tell me why it is not returning proper results when I include the mday column, it would be even better. I am quite keen to learn all this on my own and have been making some progress, but I seem to be quite properly (and very frustratingly) stuck... Thanks!

Edit: To clarify what it is I am trying to achieve: I measured every few days and in between those measurements a bunch of stuff happened (bbb). I need the accumulated amount of bbb for each measurement day. If I measured on doy 1 and again on doy 6 (which would make them mday 1 and mday 2), I need the bbb for doy 2,3,4,5,6 and assign this sum to mday 2. In the end this should be a new column in the dataframe with values for each mday (except the first). I need to still have doy in this dataframe as well, so I can use this doy-accumulated-mday-relationship for other purposes.

Edit2: I hope this works as a reproducible example. Let me know if it doesnt.

```
doy<-c(202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209)
bbb<-c(5.5,4,8.1,9,6,1.7,6.9,4.6)
mday<-c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,3)
df<-data.frame(doy,bbb,mday)

## expected output: a new column for accumulated bbb for each 
## measurement day, ie for mday 2: 21.1 and for mday 3: 19.2
```

Comment: If your question has not been answered, it would be very useful for you to create a reproducible sample matrix with an expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the presumption that vector `mday` always has a valid endpoint, i.e. a value != NA, we will use the function `na.fill()` from package *zoo* to fill the missings, use function `ceiling()` from *base R* to round, and the functionality of the *data.table* package for aggregation:

```
# load packages
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

# create dataset    
doy <- c(202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209)
bbb <- c(5.5, 4, 8.1, 9, 6, 1.7, 6.9, 4.6)
mday <- c(1, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3)

# create data.table
dt <- data.table(doy, bbb, mday)

# fill NA's with linear interpolation and round to next higher number (e.g. 1.1 -> 2)
dt$mday <- ceiling(na.fill(mday, "extend"))

# sum bbb by group mday
dt[, .(day = sum(bbb)), by = mday]
```

giving us a nice summary with

```
   mday  day
1:    1  5.5
2:    2 21.1
3:    3 19.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is incorrect `sum(df$bbb[df$mday],na.rm=T)` because you are returning all values of `df$mday` which are then used to pull out the positions in `df$bbb`. It is the equvalent to this for example: `df$bbb[c(1,NA,3,NA,5)]`. What you actually want is the *position* of the values in `df$mday` not the values themselves. In this code:

```
df$doy==1:4
```

the value returned will be a logical (TRUE, FALSE, TRUE TRUE etc) and that is used to subset your other object.

If I understand your question correctly, you want the sum of `bbb` for all the values of `mday` that are not `NA`. A simple solution would be to create a new subset dataframe where no `NA` exists and then sum `bbb`:

```
df2 <- df[complete.cases(df),]
sum(df2$bbb)
```

But to directly answer your question you want *position* of the all values in `mday`. To get this:

```
pos_mday <- which(!is.na(df$mday))
df$bbb[pos_mday]
```

or in logical format (same result)

```
pos_mday <- !is.na(df$mday) 
df$bbb[pos_mday]
```

Hope that answers your question

Comment: Thank you! I edited to clarify slightly. Are you saying that by using values in the square brackets, I am always telling r that I am talking about the position rather than the value in that column?! That wouldnt be useful to me. Surely it is possible to tell r to use a value in one column, based on the value in the same row of a different column? The numbers in the mday column are really only there to find the correct bbb values. The NAs in between shouldnt interfere, but I cant exclude the rows with NA either, as it wouldnt lead to the correct result.

Comment: Like I said in my post, when you subset using `[]` it will subset by position, not by value. I'll try to revise my answer now that you've clarified your question.